# How to move the cursor in SML/NJ's REPL in terminal on Mac?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

In the terminal of Mac OSX, I open `SML`, if I type something wrong, I wish to move my cursor to that place to modify something or add/delete something, but once I hit `<-` (the left arrow ) on the keyboard, the `REPL` gives me

[image]

Yes, that `^[[D` thing.

So how do I move the cursor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the REPL of SML/NJ does not support arrow keys. You can use the [`rlwrap` tool](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap) to fix this. That allows you to use the left and right arrow keys to navigate within a line and the up and down arrow keys to recall lines you've entered earlier.

If you're using Emacs to write your SML files, you can also run SML in an Emacs buffer.

Comment: could you please review my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759932/simple-non-optimal-unionfind-in-ocaml ?