# Java 8 Nashorn: Console pretty unusable

Tags: java-8, nashorn

I am using Java 8 build 1.8.0-b132 on OSX 10.9.2.

I am playing with Nashorn the new JavaScript runtime in Java 8.

I am using `Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jjs` but unfortunately `jjs` is pretty unusable in interactive mode since cursor left/right does not work:

> jjs
>   jjs> var x =^[[D

The above output (^[[D) is the result of pressing 'cursor left'. Is there a way to fix that behavior and using cursor left/right in the jjs console?

Comment: you may find related things [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22^[[D%22), for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489635/how-to-move-the-cursor-in-sml-njs-repl-in-terminal-on-mac

Comment: if you want to access nashorn from a console from web http://lorenzoongithub.github.io/nudge4j/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks to @assylias for pointing me to [`rlwrap`](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap).

I installed rlwrap via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install rlwrap
```

Then I defined an alias in my .zshrc (would be the same for bash in .bashrc)

```
alias jjs='rlwrap /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jjs'
```

Now I can use `jjs` on the commandline and the <- and -> keys are working as expected.

Comment: better alias jjs='rlwrap $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)/bin/jjs'