# New to scripting with Java and Nashorn, any tutorials?

Tags: java, javascript, java-8, nashorn

Are there any good tutorials or the likes for getting stated with this? I have yet to do any scripting in Java, though I am familiar with JavaScript already. Thanks. Essentially, I want to use JavaScript/XML to handle part of my project. I know Java 8 introduced JavaScript support via Nashorn. I want to learn how this works. I know it involves using javax.script, but I don't know how that package works nor do I understand how Nashorn works.

Comment: You can perhaps start from [here](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/) <-- Click

Comment: the difference between java and javascript is like the difference between apple and pineapple.  the only thing they have in common is the 'java' in the name. aside of both being programming languages.

Comment: a guy named Banana with fruit analogies, hilarious

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I didn't mean the difference between the two, I want to delegate some part of a large Java project to JavaScript, in which I will use Nashorn. It's new and I've never used it before, so I wanted to learn. I know it requires javax.script and I'm unfamiliar with how it works. There are several things like hooking into the Java code that I need to learn

Comment: That clarifies it. Add those details to your question.

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks that looks good and hopefully answers many of my questions.

Comment: A good way to get started is to fire up `jjs` and start experimenting. This is much easier than going through the JSR-223 APIs.

Answer (score 17):

I played a lot with nashorn in the last couple of weeks. I wrote all my findings in an example-driven tutorial:

http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/

It covers the following topics:

- calling javascript functions from java code
- calling java methods from javascript
- using java classes from within javascript
- summary of all language extensions (e.g. for each)

I hope it's helpful for you to start with Nashorn.

Answer (score 11):

Recently, I did couple presentations on Java and JavaScript (via Nashorn). You can find my slides and examples [here](https://github.com/gAmUssA/java-scripting-experiments).

Here is a very simple script runner implementation

```
import javax.script.*;

public class ScriptRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine nashorn = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
        String scriptName = args[0];
        Bindings bindings = nashorn.createBindings();
        bindings.put("scriptFileName", scriptName);
        nashorn.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
        nashorn.eval("load('src/main/resources/javascript/' + scriptFileName)");
    }
```

}

test.js that you can pass as an application parameter.

```
print("This is hello from test.js");
```

Also, there is a tool `jjs` that comes with JDK8. It's CLI JavaScript interpreter. It can be used to write shell scripts in JavaScript and Java. (Good [SO advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313797/java-8-nashorn-console-pretty-unusable) how to improve `jjs` on osx, linux).
Here is an example of such script

```
#!/usr/local/bin/jjs -scripting

var currentDir = new java.io.File('.'),
    allFiles = currentDir.list();
print(currentDir.getCanonicalPath());
for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
    print(allFiles[i]);
}
```

Feel free to ask question if you have any.

Thanks,

Vik

Comment: eval is evil dont use it..

Comment: Nashorn `eval` is not the same as JS `eval`

Answer (score 2):

Nashorn is accessed through the standard Java JSR 223 scripting APIs.

A good generic example is here:

http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/jsr-223-scripting-for-the-java-platform/215801163

Nashorn specific guidance is here:

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+jsr223+engine+notes

Here's an example from my code loading static library scripts and building an Invocable custom function:

```
public class ScriptRunner {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScriptRunner.class);
    private static final String ENGINE = "nashorn";
    private String functions;

    public ScriptRunner() throws IOException {
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        Resource[]  resources = resolver.getResources("your/class/path/*.js");
        log.debug("Found {} script resources", resources.length);
        StringBuilder functions = new StringBuilder();
        for (Resource resource : resources) {
            functions.append(IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream()));
        }
        this.functions = functions.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Build an Invocable script.
     * @param script The function code.
     * @return Compiled, invocable script.
     */
    public Invocable buildInvocable(String script) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName(ENGINE);
        engine.eval(functions);
        engine.eval(script);
        return (Invocable) engine;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice, very basic "getting started" video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cxyg22C5gcw

Julien Ponge has also written a good introductory article:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html

I would also recommend the Nashorn Wiki for the formal documentation:

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Main