# How to call Nashorn from Java

Tags: windows, typeerror, nashorn

I have a batfile that I want to call from java. I made a nashorn script, that runs successfully from commandline and from Netbeans 'run' command. Here it is:

```
#!C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin -fv
$ENV.PWD = 'C:/Hydromodel/MapGenerate';
$EXEC("cmd /c start cmd_all.bat");
print ('finished!');
```

I try to call the script from java this way:

```
    public class RunCmd {

    public void nashornTest()   {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    try {
        Object eval = engine.eval("load('src/simple/a_test.js');");
        //Object eval = engine.eval(new FileReader("C:/_Udvikling/Maven/realtid_2014/src/main/java/simple/a_test.js"));
    } catch (Exception ex ) {
        Logger.getLogger(CmdTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
}
```

}

Both ways I get this error:

```
Severe:   javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot load script from src/simple/a_test.js in <eval> at line number 1
```

Even if the javascript file is reduced to:

```
print ('hello!');
```

I also tried [this SO proposed way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644441/new-to-scripting-with-java-and-nashorn-any-tutorials?rq=1)
The Error stays.
I googled, but most people seem to use Linux or Mac when writing about Nashorn.
Should I do anything special to call Nashorn from java on a Windows box?

mbwiese

I am running Netbeans 8 and JDK 8 with Glassfish 4.1 on Windows 7